# SDN/RX Custom Query @RelationshipProperties mapping depth

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am stumbling on an issue with SDN/RX 1.1

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rx-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

When using a custom query on a ***repository*** class, and trying to query multiple relationships with properties.

I have two relationship properties :

```
@RelationshipProperties
public class InRegionProperties {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String location;
  private int distance;

  public InRegionProperties (String location, int distance) {
    this.id=null;
    this.location = location;
    this.distance = distance;
  }

  public Long getId () {
    return id;
  }

  public String getLocation () {
    return location;
  }

  public int getDistance () {
    return distance;
  }

  public void setLocation (String location) {
    this.location = location;
  }

  public void setDistance (int distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
  }

  public void setId (Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

and

```
@RelationshipProperties
public class InWorldProperties {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String location;

  public InWorldProperties (String location) {
    this.id=null;
    this.location = location;
  }

  public Long getId () {
    return id;
  }

  public String getLocationInWorld () {
    return location;
  }

  public void setLocationInWorld (String location) {
    this.location = location;
  }

  public void setId (Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

For ***two nodes***, a ***Region*** node and a ***World*** node. I have a last node, a ***Lieu*** node, all related this way :

***(l:Lieu)-[:IN_REGION{location, distance}]->(r:Region)-[:IN_WORLD{location}]->(w:World)***

I then use a custom query on the WorldRepository to fetch regions in a world, and then fetch lieux in a Region.

```
@Query("MATCH (r:`Region`)-[:IN_WORLD]->(n:`World`) WHERE id(r)=$regionId WITH n, id(n) AS __internalNeo4jId__ "
      + "RETURN n{.description, __internalNeo4jId__: id(n), .name, __nodeLabels__: labels(n), "
      + "World_IN_WORLD_Region:[(n)<-[__relationship__:IN_WORLD]-(n_regions:Region) | n_regions{.description, __internalNeo4jId__: id(n_regions), .name, __nodeLabels__: labels(n_regions), "
      + "Region_IN_REGION_Lieu: [(n_regions)<-[__relationship__:`IN_REGION`]-(n_regions_lieux:Lieu) | n_regions_lieux{.description, __internalNeo4jId__: id(n_regions_lieux), .name, __nodeLabels__: labels(n_regions_lieux), __relationship__}], __relationship__}]"
      + "}")
  Mono<World> getByRegion(Long regionId);
```

This is where the issue occurs :

To fetch all the **relationsipProperties**, it seems that the SDN/RX mapping engine only accepts ****relationship**** as an alias for the relationship.
The result of this query in Cypher (Neo4j browser) is :

```
{
  "name": "New Finn City",
  "description": "Ville Monde, terre de la Ligue Des Héros.",
  "__internalNeo4jId__": 61,
  "World_IN_WORLD_Region": [
    {
      "__internalNeo4jId__": 14,
      "__relationship__": {
"identity": 4,
"start": 14,
"end": 61,
"type": "IN_WORLD",
"properties": {
"location": "Sud Est"
        }
      },
      "name": "Bio Town",
      "description": "Le quartier réserve naturelle. La biosphère, en constante évolution grâce au Weillenium, y est préservée et vit en liberté protégée et surveillée.",
      "Region_IN_REGION_Lieu": [],
      "__nodeLabels__": [
        "Region"
      ]
    },
    {
      "__internalNeo4jId__": 15,
      "__relationship__": {
"identity": 3,
"start": 15,
"end": 61,
"type": "IN_WORLD",
"properties": {
"location": "Nord"
        }
      },
      "name": "Astro Town",
      "description": null,
      "Region_IN_REGION_Lieu": [],
      "__nodeLabels__": [
        "Region"
      ]
    },
    {
      "__internalNeo4jId__": 13,
      "__relationship__": {
"identity": 2,
"start": 13,
"end": 61,
"type": "IN_WORLD",
"properties": {
"location": "Est"
        }
      },
      "name": "Electro Town",
      "description": "Le quartier des savants et inventeurs, où les robots et machines alimentées en Weillenium sont omniprésentes.",
      "Region_IN_REGION_Lieu": [],
      "__nodeLabels__": [
        "Region"
      ]
    },
    {
      "__internalNeo4jId__": 12,
      "__relationship__": {
"identity": 1,
"start": 12,
"end": 61,
"type": "IN_WORLD",
"properties": {
"location": "Nord Ouest"
        }
      },
      "name": "Dark Town",
      "description": "Le quartier pauvre, rongé par la criminalité, et le traffic de Weillenium. C'est le territoire de la Ligue des Villains.",
      "Region_IN_REGION_Lieu": [],
      "__nodeLabels__": [
        "Region"
      ]
    },
    {
      "__internalNeo4jId__": 11,
      "__relationship__": {
"identity": 0,
"start": 11,
"end": 61,
"type": "IN_WORLD",
"properties": {
"location": "Sud Ouest"
        }
      },
      "name": "Atom Town",
      "description": "Le quartier central de New Finn City, où siège la Ligue des Héros. C'est le centre administratif du monde.",
      "Region_IN_REGION_Lieu": [],
      "__nodeLabels__": [
        "Region"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "__nodeLabels__": [
    "World"
  ]
}
```

The ***Lieux*** nodes are not fetched due to the redondant use of ****relationship**** as an alias. When using another alias on cypher for the :IN_REGION relationship, I get the fetched Lieux, but in SDN/RX I get the following error :

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.value.Uncoercible: Cannot coerce NULL to Relationship
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.value.ValueAdapter.asRelationship(ValueAdapter.java:311)
    at org.neo4j.springframework.data.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jConverter.createInstanceOfRelationships(DefaultNeo4jConverter.java:499)
    at org.neo4j.springframework.data.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jConverter.lambda$populateFrom$6(DefaultNeo4jConverter.java:375)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:380)
    at org.neo4j.springframework.data.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jConverter.map(DefaultNeo4jConverter.java:288)
    at org.neo4j.springframework.data.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jConverter.lambda$createInstanceOfRelationships$22(DefaultNeo4jConverter.java:496)
    at org.neo4j.springframework.data.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jConverter$KnownObjects.computeIfAbsent(DefaultNeo4jConverter.java:566)
    at org.neo4j.springframework.data.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jConverter.createInstanceOfRelationships(DefaultNeo4jConverter.java:495)
    at org.neo4j.springframework.data.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jConverter.lambda$populateFrom$6(DefaultNeo4jConverter.java:375)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:380)
    at org.neo4j.springframework.data.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jConverter.map(DefaultNeo4jConverter.java:288)
    at org.neo4j.springframework.data.core.mapping.DefaultNeo4jConverter.read(DefaultNeo4jConverter.java:138)
    ... 48 more
```

The mapping enging seems to only accept ****relationship**** as an alias for a relationship that has properties to be mapped in a @RelationshipProperties class.

Is there a way to bypass this issue?

Thank you all for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: There is now the official SDN 6 in place that is the successor of SDN/RX. We stopped the development on SDN/RX half a year ago and focused on the new SDN.
SDN 6 can be used with Spring Boot starting with version 2.4.

The relationship naming big is something we have for example fixed in the past months.

If there is really no chance for you to update, I could have a look. Please add a comment if needed.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, and sorry for the late reply.

I managed to bypass the issue, and I probably will migrate to SDN6 soon enough. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Please don't tell me that this package is deprecated: https://github.com/neo4j/sdn-rx. If so, sorry to say but if you're working on something else, that is not backwards compatible I won't use it. Because then half a year later you change your mind and start something else again.